# Why does Explorer put the new file (in an opened folder) at the bottom? Why not updating scroll position?

Tags: windows-7, windows, windows-explorer

Let's say I opened a folder in Explorer. It contains some amount of files, so that the overflow appears and scrollbar becomes visible. The files are ordered, say, by creation date, so that the newest file is at the top. And now, some application creates a new file in this folder, and I see the behavior which annoys me very much. Two questions:
1. Why is the new file being appended at the bottom of the opened folder? It must be at the top! Why not updating the entire view?
2. If it appears at the very bottom, **why not scrolling the folder to the very bottom at the same time**?. The scroll position remains the same, so that the new file is just hidden!
Is there any way to control this?

Comment: Try F5 to refresh the folder view.

Comment: No, this is not an option. Too inconvenient. This will waste too much of my time. I need an **automatic update after the new file has been created**, is there a way to achieve this?

Comment: According to [this](http://www.tomshardware.com/forum/35770-63-please-make-stop-drives-nuts#10653665) it was never fixed in Windows 7, but was added in 8. In the link there is a workaround, but it requires installing a program.